Symfony 7.1 command php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import
I'm using symfony 7.1 and I want to generate entities from my existing tables but it seems it doesn't work. First I run this command php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity I've got message tell me import command was not found. WhenI tried to use php bin/console make:entity --regenerate it was like creating new entity.
Any suggestions how to generate all entities using one command ?
Thanks.

This question is similar to: Symfony 7.1: How to generate entities from existing database. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


The doctrine:mapping:import command used to generate Doctrine entities
from existing databases was deprecated by Doctrine in 2019 and there's
no replacement for it.
Instead, you can use the make:entity command from Symfony Maker Bundle
to help you generate the code of your Doctrine entities. This command
requires manual supervision because it doesn't generate entities from
existing databases.

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html
There isn't currently a command to generate all entities using one command.
As for make:entity, try:
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App


I tried it but it gives me [ERROR] No entities were found in the "App" namespace.

@zackzulg Can you try
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate
and then when it prompts you for a class/file name you give it the full path (so for example App\Entity\NAME)
Check you namespace inside the files too



If that doesn't work then I don't know either, sorry
